# Python access modifiers as a decorator

Tags: python, oop, python-decorators, access-modifiers

Is it possible to implement `protected` and `private` access modifiers for classes with decorators in python? How?

The functionality should be like the code below:

```
class A:
    
    def public_func(self):
        self.protected_func()    # Runs without warning and error    (Because is called in the owner class)
        self.private_func()      # Runs without warning and error    (Because is called in the owner class)
    
    @protected
    def protected_func(self):
        print('protected is running')
        self.private_func()      # Runs without warning and error    (Because is called in the owner class)
    
    @private
    def private_func(self):
        print(f'private is running')


a = A()
a.public_func()      # Runs without any warning and error            (Because has no access modifier)
a.protected_func()   # Runs with protected warning
a.private_func()     # Raises Exception
```

The idea for this question was being accessable private functions as below:

```
class A:

    def __private_func(self):
        print('private is running')

a = A()
a._A__private_function()
```

If we define `private` with `decorator`, then have not to define it with `__name`.
So `_A__private_function` will not exist and the private function is really not inaccessible from outside of the owner class.

Is the idea a True solution to solve the problem below?
`__name is not realy private`

Comment: *"_name is protected and __name is private"* No, they are not. One underscore is a convention for "should be used privately" and two underscores mean "subject to name mangling".

Comment: Nothing in Python is "really" private. A leading attribute says it is private. That is a convention users of your library are expected to follow or void the warranty. The correct solution is to accept that instead of reinventing the language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77819128/6890912) of mine, in trying to determine whether a call is made from code defined in the same class as a protected method, I made use of the `co_qualname` attribute of a code object, which was only [introduced](https://bugs.python.org/issue46652) in Python 3.11, making the solution incompatible with earlier Python versions.

Moreover, using the fully qualified name of a function or code for a string-based comparison means that it would be difficult, should there be a need, to allow inheritance to work, where a method in a subclass should be able to call a protected method of the parent class without complaints. It would be difficult because the subclass would have a different name from that of the parent, and because the parent class may be defined in a closure, resulting in a fully qualified name that makes it difficult for string-based introspections to reliably work.

To clarify, if we are to allow protected methods to work from a subclass, the following usage should run with the behaviors as commented:

```
class C:
    def A_factory(self):
        class A:
            @protected
            def protected_func(self):
                print('protected is running')
                self.private_func()

            @private
            def private_func(self):
                print('private is running')

        return A

a = C().A_factory()

class B(a):
    def foo(self):
        super().private_func()

b = B()
b.foo()  # Runs without complaint because of inheritance
b.protected_func()  # Runs with protected warning
b.private_func()  # Raises Exception
```

We therefore need a different approach to determining the class in which a protected method is defined. One such approach is to recursively trace the [referrer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.get_referrers) of objects, starting from a given code object, until we obtain a class object.

Tracing recursively the referrers of an object can be potentially costly, however. Given the vast interconnectedness of Python objects, it is important to limit the recursion paths to only referrer types that can possibly lead to a class.

Since we know that the code object of a method is always referenced by a function object, and that a function object is either referenced by the `__dict__` of a class (whose type is a subclass of `type`) or a [cell object](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#function.__closure__) in a tuple representing a function closure that leads to another function and so on, we can create a dict that maps the current object type to a list of possible referrer types, so that the function `get_class`, which searches for the class closest to a code object, can stay laser-focused:

```
from gc import get_referrers
from types import FunctionType, CodeType, CellType

referrer_types = {
    CodeType: [FunctionType],
    FunctionType: [dict, CellType],
    CellType: [tuple],
    tuple: [FunctionType],
    dict: [type]
}

def get_class(obj):
    if next_types := referrer_types.get(type(obj)):
        for referrer in get_referrers(obj):
            if issubclass(referrer_type := type(referrer), type):
                return referrer
            if referrer_type in next_types and (cls := get_class(referrer)):
                return cls
```

With this utility function in place, we can now create decorators that return a wrapper function that validates that the class defining the decorated function is within the [method resolution order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) of the class defining the caller's code. Use a [`weakref.WeakKeyDictionary`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakKeyDictionary) to cache the code-to-class mapping to avoid a potential memory leak:

```
import sys
import warnings
from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary

def make_protector(action):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            func_code = func.__code__
            if func_code not in class_of:
                class_of[func_code] = get_class(func_code)
            caller_code = sys._getframe(1).f_code
            if caller_code not in class_of:
                class_of[caller_code] = get_class(caller_code)
            if not (class_of[caller_code] and
                    class_of[func_code] in class_of[caller_code].mro()):
                action(func.__qualname__)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        class_of = WeakKeyDictionary()
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@make_protector
def protected(name):
    warnings.warn(f'{name} is protected.', stacklevel=3)

@make_protector
def private(name):
    raise Exception(f'{name} is private.')
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/o5aQae

Answer (score 4):

You can make a decorator that wraps the decorated method with a function that validates the caller's fully qualified name against the fully qualified name of the decorated function. If they do not share the same parent name, produce a warning or raise an exception:

```
import sys
import warnings

def make_protector(action):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if not sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_qualname.startswith(parent):
                action(func.__qualname__)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        parent = func.__qualname__[:func.__qualname__.rfind('.') + 1]
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@make_protector
def protected(name):
    warnings.warn(f'{name} is protected.')

@make_protector
def private(name):
    raise Exception(f'{name} is private.')
```

so that:

```
class A:
    @protected
    def protected_func(self):
        print('protected is running')
        self.private_func()

    @private
    def private_func(self):
        print(f'private is running')

a = A()
a.protected_func()  # Runs with protected warning
a.private_func()  # Raises Exception
```

outputs:

```
protected is running
private is running
```

and produces:

```
/ATO/code:16: UserWarning: A.protected_func is protected.
  warnings.warn(f'{name} is protected.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/ATO/code", line 34, in <module>
    a.private_func()  # Raises Exception
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/ATO/code", line 8, in wrapper
    action(func.__qualname__)
  File "/ATO/code", line 20, in private
    raise Exception(f'{name} is private.')
Exception: A.private_func is private.
```

Demo [here](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVO7TsMwFB3Y_BVXYohTwFI3VAmpHVgZWBGyLMdurbZ2sB1ChfgSli7wUXwNseO8WvDk3HvuOcfH8ed3efAbo4_Hr8rLm9ufiwe1L4314A4OpW3NrFZ67RAqhIQ92wpaWuMF98Zixr0yOl8gaFboF4Iby0JLVpqnRtesLStLYfGM2bW7htlsW4fdCBWWkqBNtEDoWnhp2V7geU4k5aYQhBv6UrGdbqrEeWa9q5Xf4JJZof0JVVitxWiH0H6U0nyCtMJXVkNAndnrga0G3MEZ2dPirESsVLrAGclyuIL5MzqRSmGgUakPD6HlNOiYffoSBQ4K6ajd9ZCwwTJ7D70PUG6ANw7-I1SvzIsxnWXKCbh_46JsY5sQRnik4zvmHKzaoWUv1f8HfYXGSJ3YydHdNEza46wHBXZb6XCQbIg7DJEk2tI0wkkvFkdqI9CfWjJLmKkUYs1trhpeRk4c5wCX8FhpB-H3Gs7TBR4nxtYiPqTnhvjaZ5VeV_fKfgE)

Comment: Does it work with inheritance? (I think not; asking just in case I missed something)

Comment: Nice solution! It works on the demo but doesn't work on my system and other online code runners like w3schools and etc.
the problem is `f_code.co_qualname` in the line
`if not sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_qualname.startswith(parent):`
It raises exception: 
`AttributeError: 'code' object has no attribute 'co_qualname'`

Comment: @anatolyg I tried inheritance in the [Demo](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVNLbsMgEF10xymQujBOW6TsqkiVkkg9RVUhgiFBSYACrhtVPUk32bSH6mkKNnb8adkY3rx5b2Ywn9_m5Hdanc9fpRd39z9XG3k02nroTg6kbUWtkmrrACi4gEe658RY7Tnz2iLKvNQqXwAYVowXnGlLY0iUiqVAG6wsNYZbNKN2627hbLav4q7HiksKqHRdAiZb7oWlR47mORaE6YJjpslLSQ8qoNh5ar2rpN8hQy1XfiQVV1NiXQ4mXSoh-YBpuS-tgpE1Ka8jNh7wAU7EnhYTCFshVYEynOXwBs6fwcgqDQP0oG54ACyHg65nn068QNEhtdpeD44bJLL3GPuA0l3ooYL_BOUr9bwvZ6l0HD6-MW6asQ0Ea3otxw7UObhqkpadVfcfdAipR-r4QfTuJigpj7KOFNVtqWIj2WXcMQkn00YmGCe_Guy59Uh_eokscYZWbSNrtEopJhwDTMMtr4LfJnzX0ZfiUUshNoXANR1XvBkBzVNLL659eb8).
It works.

Comment: I think by inheritance @anatolyg was referring to calling a protected method from a method of a subclass. To support inheritance I've also switched to an object-based approach with my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77824225/6890912).

Answer (score 2):

Let's check access conditions in `get_is_access_limit_met()` function.
Recursive calls and calling a function from another file (not calling a method from a class) is included too.

```
import sys
import functools


class PrivateFunctionCalledException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, error_message):
        super().__init__(error_message)


def get_is_access_limit_met(func, args, caller_name, func_name, caller_file):
    
    is_file_method = type(args[0]).__name__ == 'str'
    owner_file_name = func.__module__
    called_in_the_same_file = owner_file_name == '__main__' or caller_file in ['__main__', owner_file_name]
    called_by_owner_file = is_file_method and called_in_the_same_file
    
    called_by_owner_class = caller_name in dir(args[0])
    
    called_by_owner = called_by_owner_file or called_by_owner_class
    recursive_call = caller_name is func_name
    is_private_limit_met = called_by_owner or recursive_call
    
    return is_private_limit_met


def private(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        func_name = func.__name__
        caller_name = sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name
        caller_file = sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_filename.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
        
        is_private_limit_met = get_is_access_limit_met(func, args, caller_name, func_name, caller_file)
        if not is_private_limit_met:
            error_message = f'private function {func_name} called by {caller_name}'
            raise PrivateFunctionCalledException(error_message)
        
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


def protected(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        func_name = func.__name__
        caller_name = sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name
        caller_file = sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_filename.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
        
        is_protected_limit_met = get_is_access_limit_met(func, args, caller_name, func_name, caller_file)
        if not is_protected_limit_met:
            warning_message = f'protected function {func_name} called by {caller_name}'
            print(f'ProtectedMessageCalledWarning: {warning_message}')
        
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Import `private` and `protected` and use them as decorators.